# Access CQ Widget in Dialog's loadContent

Tags: aem

I have listener on dialog's loadContent and I want to access particular widget from it. Below is the code :

```
loadContent : function(dialog)
{
    var pan1 = dialog.findById("layout1");
    pan1.hide();
    console.log("pan1 ::: "+pan1); //gives null
}
```

Below are the items in dialog :

```
<items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <panel1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Slide">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <one
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="one"
                        itemId="layout2"
                        name="./one"
                        type="checkboxgroup"
                        xtype="selection">
                        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

                        </options>
                    </one>
                    <two
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="two"
                        itemId="layout1"
                        name="./two"
                        type="checkboxgroup"
                        xtype="selection">
                        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">  
                        </options>                      
                    </two>
                </items>
            </panel1>
        </items>
```

And i want to hide particular selection with option on specific condition. So firstly need to access checkboxgroup. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with the `findById` method — are you certain that it's looking for a property of "itemId"?

You could alternatively use the `getField(…)` method:

```js
var pan1 = dialog.getField("./two");
/* Not sure above why the field with name "two" has an ID of "one"? Typo? */
```

You may want to add a listener for `selectionchanged` too, so that sections are revealed when if the dropdown value is changed after load.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `id`, `instead` of `itemId`.

I had tried a similar issue and it worked with id.

Comment: can you explain with an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

As from the widgets API:-

**findById(String id)** : CQ.Ext.Component
Deprecated: Fairly useless method, since you can just use CQ.Ext.getCmp. Should be removed for 4.0
Find a component under this container at any level by id

You can rather use
dialog.find('somepropertylikeId','valueOfthatPropertyLikeLayout2')[0];